# How do I filter my javascript constant that I displayed as a table?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, filter

I have the following code that will be displayed as a table. I want to filter this content by year through my `<select id="ano">`.

All those constants are table rows `<tr>`.

It is, when I select the `<option>` 2018 I want to display as a `<tr>` ONLY those constants which contains the number "2018" within the "Data" variable.

P.S: I don't wanna "hide" what is not "2018". I want to "show" what is "2018" ONLY.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body >
    <section id="container">


        <div id="select_calendario">
            <div>
                <select id="ano">
                    <option value="2018">2018</option>
                    <option value="2019">2019</option>
                </select>
            </div>  
        </div>

        <div id="div_calendario_jogos">
            <table id="table_calendario_jogos">
                <tbody>
                    <tr id="table_header">
                        <th>Data</th>
                        <th>Hora</th>
                        <th>Oponente</th>
                        <th>Placar</th>
                        <th>Torneio</th>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>

                <tbody id="tbody_calendario_jogos">         


                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </section>  

    <script>    
            LSB_2018_JOGO_1: {
                    Data: "11/03/2019",
                    Hora: "15:00",
                    Oponente: "BMC",
                    Placar: "V, 52-42",
                    Torneio: "LSB",
                },

            LSB_2018_JOGO_2: {
                    Data: "08/04/2018",
                    Hora: "12:30",
                    Oponente: "Drink Team",
                    Placar: "D, 59-61",
                    Torneio: "LSB",
                },

            LSB_2018_JOGO_3: {
                            Data: "22/04/2019",
                            Hora: "10:30",
                            Oponente: "Nitcheroy Ballers",
                            Placar: "V, 53-40",
                            Torneio: "LSB",
                        },

            TUC_2018_JOGO_1: {
                            Data: "11/08/2018",
                            Hora: "12:30",
                            Oponente: "Unirio",
                            Placar: "D, 30-60",
                            Torneio: "TUC",
                        },

            TUC_2018_JOGO_2: {
                            Data: "15/09/2019",
                            Hora: "17:10",
                            Oponente: "UFRJ Aecs",
                            Placar: "V, 29-25",
                            Torneio: "TUC",
                        },

            TUC_2018_JOGO_3: {
                            Data: "20/10/2018",
                            Hora: "16:00",
                            Oponente: "UERJ Economia",
                            Placar: "V, 49-30",
                            Torneio: "TUC",
                        }

};


const tbody = document.getElementById('tbody_calendario_jogos');

for (const key in jogos2018) {
  const tr = document.createElement('tr');

  for (const item in jogos2018[key]) {

    const td = document.createElement('td');
      td.textContent = jogos2018[key][item];

      tr.appendChild(td);
  }

  tbody.appendChild(tr);
}
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with your `LSB_2018_JOGO_#...`s? You need `=` to assign to a variable, not `:`

Comment: Also your script only runs once, you need to run the code in an event listener like `click`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't know the values you wanted to display, so I just displayed the dates:

**EDIT:** Just add more `<td>` elements for every property you want to display inside the check

```
document.getElementById("ano").addEventListener("change", function(e) {
    const tbody = document.getElementById('tbody_calendario_jogos')
    while (tbody.firstChild) {
        console.log(tbody.firstChild)
        tbody.removeChild(tbody.firstChild)
    }
    for (key in data) {
        const re = new RegExp(`${e.target.value}`)
        const isVal = re.exec(data[key].Data)
        if (isVal != null) {
            const obj = data[key]
            const tr = document.createElement('tr')

            const tdData = document.createElement('td')
            tdData.textContent = obj.Data

            const tdHora = document.createElement('td')
            tdHora.textContent = obj.Hora

            const tdOponente = document.createElement('td')
            tdOponente.textContent = obj.Oponente

            const tdPlacar = document.createElement('td')
            tdPlacar.textContent = obj.Placar

            const tdTorneio = document.createElement('td')
            tdTorneio.textContent = obj.Torneio

            tr.appendChild(tdData)
            tr.appendChild(tdHora)
            tr.appendChild(tdOponente)
            tr.appendChild(tdPlacar)
            tr.appendChild(tdTorneio)
            tbody.appendChild(tr)
        }
    }
})
```

**EDIT 2:** If you want a more concise way of doing this (note: the order of properties matter in this method [aka top is rendered first, bottom is rendered last]) replace the contents of `if (isVal != null) { ... }` with :

```
const obj = data[key]
const tr = document.createElement('tr')

for (value of Object.values(obj)) {
    const td = document.createElement('td')
    td.textContent = value

    tr.appendChild(td)
    console.log(value)
}

tbody.appendChild(tr)
```

This activates every time the value of the `select` changes (aka whenever the user chooses an option), removes all elements of `"tbody_calendario_jogos"`, uses Regex to filter the correct objects by their year and displays them.

PS: I organized your data into this for the code to work:

```
const data = {
    LSB_2018_JOGO_1: {
        Data: "11/03/2019",
        Hora: "15:00",
        Oponente: "BMC",
        Placar: "V, 52-42",
        Torneio: "LSB",
    },
    LSB_2018_JOGO_2: {
        Data: "08/04/2018",
        Hora: "12:30",
        Oponente: "Drink Team",
        Placar: "D, 59-61",
        Torneio: "LSB",
    },
    LSB_2018_JOGO_3: {
        Data: "22/04/2019",
        Hora: "10:30",
        Oponente: "Nitcheroy Ballers",
        Placar: "V, 53-40",
        Torneio: "LSB",
    },
    TUC_2018_JOGO_1: {
        Data: "11/08/2018",
        Hora: "12:30",
        Oponente: "Unirio",
        Placar: "D, 30-60",
        Torneio: "TUC",
    },
    TUC_2018_JOGO_2: {
        Data: "15/09/2019",
        Hora: "17:10",
        Oponente: "UFRJ Aecs",
        Placar: "V, 29-25",
        Torneio: "TUC",
    },
    TUC_2018_JOGO_3: {
        Data: "20/10/2018",
        Hora: "16:00",
        Oponente: "UERJ Economia",
        Placar: "V, 49-30",
        Torneio: "TUC",
    }
};
```

Comment: this is great!! thank you!! and what if I want to display all the other values??

Comment: Glad to be of help, I will edit my answer, but it is really just adding my `<td>` elements to the created `<tr>`.